# select onchange event with parameter

Tags: javascript, select

I create n select in a cycle:

```
selCom = document.createElement("SELECT");
selCom.setAttribute("id", ("commessa"+n));
```

I would like to assign a function to each change: (for disable other select with same index)

```
selCom.setAttribute("onchange", "OnSelectionChange(this,n)");
```

with OnSelectionChange(this) works, OnSelectionChange(this,n) not work

```
 function OnSelectionChange(select,indexDisable) {
    var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
        if ((selectedOption.value)=="Work"){
            document.getElementById("Attivita"+indexDisable).disabled=true;
        }else{
            document.getElementById("Attivita"+indexDisable).disabled=false;
        }
}
```

What is the correct form to use to also pass the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listener instead of setting the html attr like that.

```
function OnSelectionChange(indexDisable) {
    var select = this;

    var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    if ((selectedOption.value)=="Work"){
        document.getElementById("Attivita"+indexDisable).disabled=true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("Attivita"+indexDisable).disabled=false;
    }
}

selCom.addEventListener('change', function(n){
    OnSelectionChange(n);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way is to use data-* attributes

```
<div data-id="1" onclick="dataTest()">TEST!</div>
```

Then in the JS function you could access id in the following way

```
function dataTest() {
    alert(event.target.dataset.id);
}
```

here is more information about data-* attributes [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)
And, here is the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/jvallelunga/xbr9oona/)